# Test a component is rendered with React Router's render prop using Enzyme's shallow wrapper and Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

If my component is rendering the following, how can I test that `Main` is being rendered using Enzyme's shallow wrapper and Jest?

```
  <div className='App'>
    {this.state.uid &&
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Main uid={this.state.uid} />} />
      </React.Fragment>
    }
  </div>
```

Comment: how about `expect(wrapper.find('Router[path="/"]').at(0).props().render().html()).toEqual('<Main uid={what"s you uid here?} />')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. I believe it's because of the shallow render.

Comment: `expect(wrapper.find('Route[path="/"]').at(0).props().render()).toEqual(<Main uid={111} />)` passes for me

Comment: And it works for me too! Feel free to post this as the answer so I can mark this as resolved. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. we can search for `Route` as any other component with [`find()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html)
2. we can call `.render()` prop as long as we can reach `<Route>`
3. because of `shallow()` we should get `<Main ...` as a result
4. we still can refer to `wrapper.state('uid')`

So

```
expect(
  wrapper
    .find('Route[path="/"]')
    .at(0)
    .props()
    .render()
 ).toEqual(<Main uid={wrapper.state('uid')} />)
```

[UPD] I think with [`renderProp`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/renderProp.html) it should be easier to verify result:

```
expect(
  wrapper
    .find(Route)
    .filter({path: '/'})
    .renderProp('render')
    .find(Main)
    .prop('uid')
 ).toEqual(wrapper.state('uid'))
```